# Intent delivering null content to app when the app is open in onNewIntent and onResume

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I am having a app which uses ccs to get delivery of the cloud messaging.

I built up the notification using the below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GcmActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.putExtra("title",messagetype);
intent.putExtra("message", msg);
intent.putExtra("additional", additionalInfo);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_cloud) 
    .setContentTitle(messagetype)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg)
    .setTicker(msg)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(randInt(1, 1000), mBuilder.build());
```

Now when I click on the notification when app is not opened, it delivers the intent and I show them on a list.

However they are all null when clicked when the app is opened. Actually why I want this to be delivered when app is opened cause I have a broadcastreceiver which update listview which does not updated when the screen is asleep. I send the broadcast just before this code.

I know this something to do with the FLags so, I tried adding in my intent

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

With no results.

Answer (score 1):

use below Flag for when App is open:

```
setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
```

thats it...

Comment: for pending intent? if yes then how do i check if app is open. Please help me out.

Comment: you do not need to check app is open or close just set this flag to your intent.

Comment: No @Jay...its not working,....its same null value retrival in onnewintent and onnewresume

Comment: I am really sorry the value was getting delivered well however I was trying to get them using a null variable...thanx for the help @Jay though